# Create UIImage from SVG HTML String

Tags: swift, svg

**If anything in this question is vague, confusing, or ambiguous, please leave a comment so I know what to clarify. Thanks in advance.**

**What I am attempting to implement**

I am trying to convert a locally loaded SVG from HTML String format to an image format that can be used in a UIImageView using Xcode and Swift 4.

**What I have managed so far**

I managed to load the HTML string correctly and display it in a WKWebView.
The problem with this solution is that the SVG size and location cannot be modified directly. This is important when working with different screen sizes.

**SVG source**

The SVG data is stored in a div in a local HTML file.

Here's the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <!-- Raphael.js is used for drawing-->
    <script src="./lib/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="333.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

            var myCompuation = compute["333"].getOutput()
            var computation = myComputation.result_string;

            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            var resultImage = compute["333"].drawResult(newDiv, myComputation.state, 100, 80);
            document.appendChild(newDiv);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The method drawResult outputs an SVG, which is added to an html element (newDiv). The other arguments in drawResult are the canvas frame properties.

**HTML String (data)**

```
<svg height="80" version="1.1" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.0.0</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,3.5L26.5,11.5L33.5,11.5L33.5,3.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000"

d="M33.5,3.5L33.5,11.5L41.5,11.5L41.5,3.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,3.5L41.5,11.5L48.5,11.5L48.5,3.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,11.5L26.5,18.5L33.5,18.5L33.5,11.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,11.5L33.5,18.5L41.5,18.5L41.5,11.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,11.5L41.5,18.5L48.5,18.5L48.5,11.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,18.5L26.5,26.5L33.5,26.5L33.5,18.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,18.5L33.5,26.5L41.5,26.5L41.5,18.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,18.5L41.5,26.5L48.5,26.5L48.5,18.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M51.5,28.5L51.5,36.5L58.5,36.5L58.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M58.5,28.5L58.5,36.5L66.5,36.5L66.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M66.5,28.5L66.5,36.5L73.5,36.5L73.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M51.5,36.5L51.5,43.5L58.5,43.5L58.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M58.5,36.5L58.5,43.5L66.5,43.5L66.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M66.5,36.5L66.5,43.5L73.5,43.5L73.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M51.5,43.5L51.5,51.5L58.5,51.5L58.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M58.5,43.5L58.5,51.5L66.5,51.5L66.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M66.5,43.5L66.5,51.5L73.5,51.5L73.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,28.5L26.5,36.5L33.5,36.5L33.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,28.5L33.5,36.5L41.5,36.5L41.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,28.5L41.5,36.5L48.5,36.5L48.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,36.5L26.5,43.5L33.5,43.5L33.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,36.5L33.5,43.5L41.5,43.5L41.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,36.5L41.5,43.5L48.5,43.5L48.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,43.5L26.5,51.5L33.5,51.5L33.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,43.5L33.5,51.5L41.5,51.5L41.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,43.5L41.5,51.5L48.5,51.5L48.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M1.5,28.5L1.5,36.5L8.5,36.5L8.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M8.5,28.5L8.5,36.5L16.5,36.5L16.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M16.5,28.5L16.5,36.5L23.5,36.5L23.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M1.5,36.5L1.5,43.5L8.5,43.5L8.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M8.5,36.5L8.5,43.5L16.5,43.5L16.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M16.5,36.5L16.5,43.5L23.5,43.5L23.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M1.5,43.5L1.5,51.5L8.5,51.5L8.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M8.5,43.5L8.5,51.5L16.5,51.5L16.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M16.5,43.5L16.5,51.5L23.5,51.5L23.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M76.5,28.5L76.5,36.5L83.5,36.5L83.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M83.5,28.5L83.5,36.5L91.5,36.5L91.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M91.5,28.5L91.5,36.5L98.5,36.5L98.5,28.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M76.5,36.5L76.5,43.5L83.5,43.5L83.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M83.5,36.5L83.5,43.5L91.5,43.5L91.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M91.5,36.5L91.5,43.5L98.5,43.5L98.5,36.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M76.5,43.5L76.5,51.5L83.5,51.5L83.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M83.5,43.5L83.5,51.5L91.5,51.5L91.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ff8000" stroke="#000000" 

d="M91.5,43.5L91.5,51.5L98.5,51.5L98.5,43.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,53.5L26.5,61.5L33.5,61.5L33.5,53.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,53.5L33.5,61.5L41.5,61.5L41.5,53.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,53.5L41.5,61.5L48.5,61.5L48.5,53.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,61.5L26.5,68.5L33.5,68.5L33.5,61.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,61.5L33.5,68.5L41.5,68.5L41.5,61.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,61.5L41.5,68.5L48.5,68.5L48.5,61.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M26.5,68.5L26.5,76.5L33.5,76.5L33.5,68.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#0000ff" stroke="#000000" 

d="M33.5,68.5L33.5,76.5L41.5,76.5L41.5,68.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><path fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" 

d="M41.5,68.5L41.5,76.5L48.5,76.5L48.5,68.5Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path></svg>
```

**Getting the SVG in the Swift file**

In the Swift file, I retrieve the SVG data using `evaluateJavascript`:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("newDiv.innerHTML") { (innerHTML, error) in

      dump(error)
      self.webView.loadHTMLString(innerHTML as? String ?? " ", baseURL: nil) 

}
```

The above HTML string data is stored in `innerHTML`.
**A temporary but insufficient solution**

Calling `self.webView.loadHTMLString` inside `evaluateJavaScript` outputs the image correctly, but I can't resize or position it like a UIImage.

**How I attempted to modify the HTML**

Instead of using fixed dimensions in the drawResult function in the HTML file, I tried using `100%` so that the output would fill the container like so:

```
var resultImage = compute["333"].drawResult(newDiv, myComputation.state, 100%, 100%);
```

Unfortunately, the container is apparently not recognized and I get this error: `WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: newDiv`.

It's a total of 54 different d paths with different fill colors, which is the expected output.

I'm kind of lost here and would really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE: Another (unsuccessful) attempt**

Another potential solution I tried was to convert the innerHTML result to Data using the following line:

```
let htmlString = innerHTML as! String           
let data = htmlString.data(using: .utf8)! // I know this force-unwrap shouldn't be here
```

And then create a UIImage from the data:

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)! // I know this force-unwrap shouldn't be here
```

This caused the app to crash at the above line (`let image`...) because the UIImage was nil, but the data was not. How is this possible?
Logically, creating a UIImage from non-nil data shouldn't return a nil image. I'm definitely missing something here. Would appreciate any suggestions.

(Swift 4, Xcode 11)

Comment: Are you want to have HTML data without the SVG data or only extract SVG data to use it later?

Comment: -Same7Farouk - I'm trying to get the SVG data to pass into SwiftSVG's methods for use in a UIImageView.

Comment: Can you share the HTML Data?

Comment: -Same7Farouk - I added the data returned from the evaluateJavascript call.

Comment: Malformed data cannot be used to create UIImage. UIImage doesn't support svg yet